# Prevent Android apps theft from Google Play

Tags: google-play, licensing, apk

I recently noticed that several of my paid apps from Google Store are available for free on a couple of shady sites.
My assumption is that these sites use Google Play as a backend leveraging the brilliant refund mechanism

Is there a way to **block APK installation** from unknown sources?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if they were doing that.  Can you link the sites in question? It's more likely they're hosting a direct link to the APK,  which was been shared by someone who got it from the Play store.

Also I know you're not looking for advice here,  but:  you'll never win this battle.  you can email the site with a takedown request,  but your time would be better spent promoting the real version of your apps available at the Play store.

Comment: downloadatoz.com, sonyandroid.com, iphoneapp.xyz, apk4funny.com and the list goes on and on... These sites download the latest version from somewhere, then host the file themselves. I cannot think of a better place than Google Play as their source.